# Laravel, add gate to see if user has access

Tags: php, laravel

I have got a table with my permissions, I want to be able to setup a route like below so that I check the logged in users permissions and see if they have got access to the edit_users page for example.

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'users', 'middleware' => 'can:access,edit_users' ], static function() {
```

I have added the following Gate, where I would do my query and check, however `$permission` is null...

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('access', static function ($user, $permission) {
        dd($user, $permission);
    });
}
```

How would I go about doing this? As I don't want to hard-code all the permissions into gates!

Comment: Not answer to your question. But I highly recommend using [Zizcao/Entrust Role Permission](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default middleware passes a route parameter as the second argument. I think what you'll need to do in this case is write your own middleware that takes a string as the argument, then do your check manually.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class HasPermission {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
    {
        if($request->user()->can('access', $permission)) {
           return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Then register your new middleware in the kernel file

```
'hasPermission' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasPermission::class
```

Then you can use your new middleware instead of the `can` middleware in your route.

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'users', 'middleware' => 'hasPermission:edit_users' ], function() {});
```

Comment: Thanks for the support!